# Symfony2 invalid form without errors

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I've got a problem with a Symfony2 generated CRUD form.
(With MongoDB Documents, but I do not think that this is related)

In my controller's createAction() method, when I debug the form result :

```
$form->isValid() // returns false

$form->getErrors() // returns en empty array(0) {}
```

So, I do not get anything using `form_errors(form)` on my twig template (which seems normal because of `$form->getErrors()` empty return)

And the written values are not replaced in the form...

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: can you edit your question to include your validation.xml or your validation annotations.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The first thing to understand is validation is done on the model, not the form. The form can contain errors, but only if it has a field mapped to the property that doesn't validate. So if your form does not contain the invalid field (maybe a `NotNull` assertion on a property that is not in the form), it will not show the error.

The second thing is that `$form->getErrors()` will only show errors for that level, each form child can contain its own errors. So if you want to check the errors, you should loop through the fields and call getErrors on each field. The `getErrors` method on the Form class can be deceiving that way.

Comment: I didn't know it, thank you, I think I have found the answer.
I'll try it !

Comment: If you did, please mark this as the accepted answer so other people with this question can benefit from it too.

Comment: I am having the same issue, I use a createForm and have a Type adding one text field. Why on earth does it create a child form?! I only have a single text field...

Comment: You can also get child errors by passing 'true' as first parameter: $form->getErrors(true)

Answer (score 63):

To debug a form, use `$form->getErrorsAsString()` instead of `$form->getErrors()`.

`$form->getErrorsAsString()` should only be used to debug the form...it will contain the errors of each child elements which is not the case of `$form->getErrors()`.

As Peter mentions, `$form->getErrors()` will not return the sum of all the errors of the children forms.

To understand how a form can be invalid and have a getErrors() returning an empty array, you can have a look at the [isValid()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L720) method of the symfony form class. As you can see, there are 2 cases where the form is not valid, the first one test for the general form, and the second case test for each child elements.

```php
public function isValid()
{
    //...

    //CASE I : IF CHILD ELEMENTS HAVE ERRORS, $this->errors WILL CONTAIN
    //THE ERROR ON THE CHILD ELEMENT AND NOT ON THE GENERAL 'errors' FIELD 
    //ITSELF

    if (count($this->errors) > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    //CASE II: AND THIS IS WHY WE ARE TESTING THE CHILD ELEMENTS AS WELL
    //TO CHECK WHETHER THERE ARE VALID OR NOT

    if (!$this->isDisabled()) {
        foreach ($this->children as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Therefore each form child can contain an error, but `$form->getErrors()` itself won't return all the errors. Considering a form that has many child elements, you will generally have $form->getErrors() with a CSRF error if the CSRF is not correct.

Comment: Big thanks for this anwser. Without it I would have to spend a lot of time to debug invalid field.

Comment: $form->getErrorsAsString() is deprecated in Symfony 2.5+

Comment: Very good point @ChristoKiwi! Feel free to update the answer if you wish!!

Comment: For deprecation warning, use `getErrors()` instead, they also say to cast to string, I ended using `(string)$form->getErrors(true);`

Comment: For Symfony 3.2, get the errors as a string like so: `$form->getErrors(true, false);`

Answer (score 59):

*Update for Symfony 2.6*

So depending on your Symfony2 version:

[symfony2.3](/questions/tagged/symfony2.3)

```
die($form->getErrorsAsString());
```

As of [symfony2.5](/questions/tagged/symfony2.5), the `getErrorsAsString()` function is deprecated (will be removed in Symfony3) and you should use the following method:

```
die((string) $form->getErrors());     // Main errors
die((string) $form->getErrors(true)); // Main and child errors
```

As of [symfony2.6](/questions/tagged/symfony2.6), you can also use the `dump` (dev environment) function if you have activated the `DebugBundle`:

```
dump((string) $form->getErrors());     // Main errors
dump((string) $form->getErrors(true)); // Main and child errors
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that !

Comment: This one helped me fix my problem, thanks! (Using Symfony 2.8)

Comment: $form->getErrors(true) nice!

Comment: $form->getErrors(true) on symfony 3.4 as well. 
Didn't know about "deep" param, which shows errors from children.

Answer (score 18):

I’ve just got the same problem. For me, the form was not valid, but I could not get any errors by using `$form->getErrors()` or `$form->getErrorsAsString()`. I later found I forgot to pass the CSRF token to the form so it won’t be submitted, and `$form->handleRequest($request)` did nothing (no validation). As I saw @pit's answer, I tried to use

```
$form->submit($request);

$form->getErrorsAsString();
```

it returned an error:

> ERROR: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

Here is some explanation in the documentation of Symfony2: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 7):

For Symfony (>= 3.2 - 4), you can use :

```
foreach($form->getErrors(true, false) as $er) {
    print_r($er->__toString());
}
```

to see the errors obviously.

Comment: I do not think it is a good practice to use the "magic" `__toString()` method directly. Easier to cast the object into a string directly, as Adam already suggested.

Comment: Of course, but, if you want to see what's wrong without too much coding, it can help.

Comment: `print_r((string) $er));` instead seems less coding to me ;) And it is even possible to directly dump `print_r((string) $form->getErrors(true, false));` without iterating.

Answer (score 4):

From Symfony 3 onwards as per documentation you should do use the new implementation:

`$errors = (string) $form->getErrors(true, false);`

This will return all errors as one string.

Answer (score 3):

For me the form was not submitted, even if I had a submit button.
I added the code to solve the problem

```
$request = $this->get('request');
if($request->isMethod("POST")){
      $form->submit($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
        // now true
        }
}
```

Comment: Looks very strange, don't you have several forms in the same page ?

Comment: Maybe you were missing the **$form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());** instruction. It should be called before the *isValid()* check.

Answer (score 3):

Yes 
it is correct, what it say **Peter Kruithof**
In SF 2.8 this is my function,to get the errors of the fields

```
 private function getErrorsForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
{
    $response =  array();

    foreach ($form as $child) {
         foreach ($child->getErrors(true) as $error) {
            $response[$child->getName()][] = $error->getMessage();
         }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Or: $form->getErrors(true)

Answer (score 2):

**If you are sending datas via AJAX**, you may have missed to include the form's name on your datas keys and therefore are "victim" of …

```
# line 100 of Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php 
// Don't submit the form if it is not present in the request
```

Which means, while trying to handle the request, the request processing mechanism did not find your form's name inside GET/POST datas (meaning as an array).

When you render a form the usual way, each of its fields contain your form's name as a prefix into their name attribute `my_form[child_field_name]`.

When using ajax, add your form's name as a prefix in datas !

```
data : {
    "my_form" : {
       "field_one" : "field_one_value"
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error and found that I was forgetting to "handle" the request. Make sure you have that around...

```
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CustomType(),$dataObject);
    /**  This next line is the one I'm talking about... */
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as you have a validation problem. The form is not validating on submitting. I am going to assume you are using Annotations for your validation.  Make sure you have this at the top of the entity.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

and also this above each property

```
/**      
 * @Assert\NotBlank()      
 */
```

The `NotBlank()` can be changed to any constraint to fit your needs.

More information on validation can be found at: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

More information on Assert constraints can be found at:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#constraints

Comment: I'm working with MongoDB, so I do not have entities but documents.
And have allready this line on my document class file, otherwise I got another PHP error or warning ;)

I suppose my error come with this annotation, because I have files fields on my form... I'll try this later.

Thank you !