# Symfony2: my form returns false from isValid() but empty array for getErrors() from unique constraint condition

Tags: forms, symfony, unique, validation

I have a Customer entity that only has a unique Email field to it. I am trying to edit a customer's email and the validation works fine. However I have this in my controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Customer')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Customer entity.');
    }


    $editForm = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $entity);
    $editForm->bind($request);
    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ticket_result'));
    }
    var_dump($editForm->getErrors());

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Customer:edit.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

The var_dump returns an empty array but the validator sets a unique error and the `$editForm->isValid()` returns false. Is there a way to check for that specific error in the controller during validation, also can you explain why it returns an empty error array? Basically, I would like to provide the "merge" option if that error comes up.

**EDIT**: here is the formtype:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CustomerType extends AbstractType {


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('email', 'email', array('required'=>true))
        ;

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Customer',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'acme_demobundle_customertype';
    }
}
```

And the twig template:

```
{% extends 'AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body -%}
    <h1>Customer edit</h1>



  <form action="{{ path('customer_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
        {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Edit</button>
        </p>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is my validation:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Customer:
    constraints:
      - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: 
          fields: email
          message: "A customer under that email address already exists"

    properties:
        email:
            - Email: ~
```

Comment: Does your customer type have any sub-forms ?

Comment: show your template, plz

Comment: I updated the post and added the validation, template and formtype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found an answer here:

[Symfony2 invalid form without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208992/symfony2-invalidform-without-errors)

It turns out each form child has it's own separate errors. When doing a var_dump of

```
$editForm->getChildren()['email']->getErrors()
```

I get:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[531]
      private 'message' => string 'A customer under that email address already exists' (length=50)
      protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'A customer under that email address already exists' (length=50)
      protected 'messageParameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'messagePluralization' => null
```

I am still wondering how to determine that the error is because of a unique conflict without parsing the error message string.

Comment: `$editForm->getErrors(true)` will now return form errors from children recursively (since 2.5).

Answer (score 22):

For debug purposes you can use `$form->getErrorsAsString()` instead of `$form->getErrors()` if you use Symfony 2.*

Quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14080384/667773):

> `$form->getErrorsAsString()` should only be used to debug the form...it
>   will contain the errors of each child elements which is not the case
>   of $form->getErrors().

---

UPDATE 1:

"With more recent Symfony versions, you must use `$form->getErrors(true, false);` instead. First param corresponds to `deep` and second to `flatten`" (see the comment by @Roubi)

Comment: getErrorsAsString is Deprecated since version 2.5, to be removed in 3.0. Use getErrors()} instead and cast the result to a string.

Comment: @DénesPapp pass the optional Boolean param to cascade through any child forms $form->getErrors(true);

Comment: With more recent Symfony versions, you must use `$form->getErrors(true, false);` instead. First param corresponds to **deep** and second to **flatten**

Answer (score 3):

The following solutions works for me:

$form->getErrors(true)

Answer (score 1):

You can use error_bubbling on each field to bubble the error up to your $form.

If not, you can also foreach through the errors

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($child->hasErrors()) {
                $vars = $child->createView()->getVars();
                $errors = $child->getErrors();
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                    $this->allErrors[$vars["name"]][] = $this->convertFormErrorObjToString($error);
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 2.3, you can use this one :

```
if ($form->isValid()){
    # Code...
} else {
    foreach ($form->getIterator() as $key => $child) {
        if ($child instanceof Form) {
            foreach ($child->getErrors() as $error) {
                $errors[$key] = $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will get you an array (`$errors`) with the errors from the children.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `dump` function when the form is submited and not valid. I use it like this

```
if($form->isSubmited() && $form->isValid()){
   //SAVE TO DATABASE AND DO YOUR STUFF
}else if($form->isSubmited()){
  //SUBMITED BUT WITH ERRORS
   dump($form->getErrors(true));
   die();

}
```

Note this is for debugging purposes only, It will show you your form, the data in it and all the errors any field could have.
In production mode you should return the error to the view and show them to the user.