# Symfony2: handleRequest() is not submitting the form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have got strange problem with handleRequest method in Symfony 2.3.5.

I am submitting form with handleRequest ($editForm->handleRequest($request)) and everything is working fine on dev. But on prod environment it is not working. I have debug everything and I found that it is not submitting this form.

I have managed to get this working with changing

```
$editForm->handleRequest($request)
```

to

```
$editForm->submit($request->request->get($editForm->getName()))
```

But could someone tell me why handleRequest is not working for me just in prod environment?

I have removed all cache.

EDIT:
I have also remind myself that it is working great on creating, but not on editing/updating.

Comment: Getting this issue while submitting datas via AJAX ? Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208992/symfony2-invalid-form-without-errors/38079913#answer-38079913)

Answer (score 9):

Are you setting the method param when creating your $editForm?

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('edit_task'),
    'method' => 'PUT',
));

$editForm->handleRequest($request);
```

Additionally you might need to set `http_method_override` in your config. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#http-method-override

Comment: weird that you didn't have to do this with $form->submit. what a headache that caused

Comment: I had this same problem, but didn't actually have to add the 'action' into the options, I only had to add the 'method' => 'PUT'.  My situation might be different as my project is only a REST API.

Comment: @JeremyZerr yeah if you're just building an API you'll never need to render a form on the front end and therefore not need action.