# symfony2 form without error is not valid

Tags: symfony

I have the following code in my controller extending BaseController, and that seems not to be working, but I am not able to see a decent error :

```
    $responseFormatter = $this->getResponseFormatter();
    $entity = new POI();
    $form = $this->createForm(new POIType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $responseFormatter->successfullResponseFormat($entity)->getResponse();
    }

    $errors = $this->formErrorFormatter($form);

    return $responseFormatter->badResponseFormat('entity.error', $errors)->getResponse();
```

I even tried the solution of $form->getErrors(true); , and it is empty on my return, so this post ( [Symfony2 invalid form without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208992/symfony2-invalid-form-without-errors) ) haven't solved my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These may also be one of the causes of not being valid.

**First: Not valid a METHOD**

Inside `[HttpFoundationRequestHandler](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L45)

```
    $name = $form->getName();
    $method = $form->getConfig()->getMethod();

    if ($method !== $request->getMethod()) {
        return;
    }
```

**Form Submitted status is false**

This makes your form not submitted. If the form's status is not submitted it will not be valid as well. Not only `errors` make your form `invalid`. Following  code demonstrates it.

Inside [isValid](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Form.php#L724) function

```
public function isValid()
{
    if (!$this->submitted) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->isDisabled()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (count($this->getErrors(true)) > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
$responseFormatter = $this->getResponseFormatter();
    $entity = new POI();
    $form = $this->createForm(new POIType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $form->isValid();
    $form->getErrorsAsString();
    exit;

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $responseFormatter->successfullResponseFormat($entity)->getResponse();
    }

    $errors = $this->formErrorFormatter($form);

    return $responseFormatter->badResponseFormat('entity.error', $errors)->getResponse();
```

I hope getErrorsAsString() function show error if any error message are occurred during validate.

Comment: This function is deprecated, and no more errors anyway

Answer (score 0):

Or have you forget [the following](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form) in your template?

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
```

If not, how have you render your form?