# REST json api with symfony 2.7, form not validating even when filled

Tags: php, json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to figure out why the form is not validating when I create one with a pre-populated entity with values coming from a json request.

Here is the controller in Symfony with the FosRestBundle already configured:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $house = new House();
    $house->setTitle($request->get('title'));
    $house->setDescription($request->get('description'));
    $house->setPostcode($request->get('postCode'));
    $house->setPhoneNumber((int) $request->get('phoneNumber'));
    $availability = $request->get('available') ? true : false;
    $house->setAvailability($availability);

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($house);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $response = new JsonResponse();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($house);
        $em->flush();

        return $response->setData(array(
            'success' => true
        ));
    }

    return $response->setData(array(
        'success' => false,
        'errors' => $this->getFormErrors($form)
    ));
}

private function createCreateForm(House $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new HouseType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('houses_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'csrf_protection' => false
    ));

    return $form;
}
```

the yaml config file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    exception:
        enabled: true
    # configure the view handler
    view:
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
    # add a content negotiation rule, enabling support for json/xml for the entire website
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: ^/, priorities: [ json, xml, html ], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
```

If I execute `$form->get('title')->getData()` for example I can see that the form is filled correctly but still doesn't pass the validation and when I execute `$this->getFormErrors($form)` I just get an empty array.

Any idea on how I could debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive json, you need to enable the body listener feature.

In your `config.yml`:

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
```

You should also [check the documentation for advanced usage](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/body_listener.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated the yml config file consequently but still having the same issue.

Comment: Does the request that you are sending contain the header "Content-Type: application/json"?

Comment: As said to sw0rdfishhhhh I just edited the issue accordingly to the latest debug, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a typo when you initiate the $form: "createCreateForm" -> it should be just "createForm".

If that doesn't work check the values from $form->getData() after the "if ($form->isValid()) { " part. I suspect the framework doesn't know how to handle the request (not coming from a standard form). It that's the case then you can set manually the values on the entity and save it.

```
$house->setStuff($request->request->get('stuff');
...
$em->persist($house);`$em->flush();`
```

Comment: How about the contents of $form->getData()? Just var_dump it.If that is empty or not helpful, try going step by step with a debugger (if you have xdebug set up). Most likely the values you need are in the $request variable.

Comment: Just did some debugging on this one today. It seems like the values are there in the form but still `$form->isValid()` returns false and when I execute `$this->getFormErrors($form)` I get an empty array.

Comment: Just edited the title and description of the issue raised accordingly. Thanks so far.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208992/symfony2-invalid-form-without-errors . Double check your constraints on the entity and the values that are set on the entity before calling isValid() .